# Цены на интернет-магазины

Tags: интернет-магазин

Нужен интернет-магазин с возможностью заказа товаров, корзиной, обратной связью и регистрацией для заказа. Возможность загрузки товаров из `csv`. Ведение количества доступной продукции, и отчеты в разных видах. В общем стандартный набор. Модульность и расширяемость. Не нудный, но без `flash` и наворотов, возможно, легкий `jQuery-Lightbox`. Не хотел бы видеть сие творение на базе `Joomla-Virtuemar`t.

Есть у кого идеи сколько в убитых енотах будет сие творение стоить? Только мотивировано пожалуйста и без рекламы.

Comment: Ценовой разброс: 5к ("магазин на костылях", фриланс, индусы и школьники, срок месяц+) - 60к ("myMegaSuperShop", пафосные компании, договора-налоги-согласование-продвижениебесплатно, срок неделя+). Больше - эксклюзив типа флэш-версий, уникального дизайна от Гуччи и пр.

Comment: @Sh4dow, 5-60к енотов?

Comment: ну если у.е. считать рублями - да)

Comment: Вы же так не пугайте. Я хотел было уже заказывать билеты на просмотр школоты, работающей в месяц за 5к баксов.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Из бесплатных могу порекомендовать:

1. [Opencart](http://www.opencart.com/) ([отечественное сообщество](http://myopencart.ru/)) - сам пользуюсь, есть все необходимые модули, как бесплатно, так и платно. Большое количество шаблонов. Ставится и настраивается за пару часов с установкой необходимых модулей, и еще день-два на подключение платежных систем. Не требует особых знаний в программировании.
2. [Prestashop](http://www.prestashop.com/) ([русская поддержка](http://prestadev.ru/)) - огромное количество модулей и шаблонов, большое сообщество. Больше возможностей по сравнению с первым движком, для крупных магазинов.

Comment: Вот за это спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста, если будет нужна помощь по установке и настройке, обращайтесь.

Comment: Да я как бы уже:) Спасибо